# gnuplottex and cairolatex for 3D plots: remove extra whitespace

Tags: gnuplot

as title says.

I'm using gnuplottex with the cairolatex terminal for both my 2D and 3D plots. While the 2D plots look great, the 3D plots have too much whitespace. I tried negative vspace, negative l/r/t/bmargin (which apparently doesn't really work), and setting the size manually. The third one results in tiny tiny tiny plots.

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions={size 7in,6in crop}]
***gnuplot code***
\end{gnuplot}
\caption []{}
\label{fig:blah}
\end{figure}
```

[image: And the result is too much whitespace. I need to fill up the width of the document, as indicated by the arrows.]

I'm not sure if "crop" is doing anything. I tried epslatex but it doesn't change anything. The document is A4-sized paper. It's the same result when using multiplot.

edit: the whitespace is a lot more when I used set view xyz. I need that, tho. Maybe it's related?

edit2: MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[cleanup, subfolder]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1.5in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex]
set parametric
set view 66,200
set view equal xyz
set ticslevel 0
set xrange [-1:3]
set yrange [-1:3]
set zrange [-1:1]
set xlabel"x"
set ylabel "y"
set zlabel "z"
r = 0.5
splot [-pi:pi][-pi/2:pi/2] r*cos(u)*cos(v), r*sin(u)*cos(v), r*sin(v) lc 3 title "sphere"
\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And how it looks

[image: too much space]

Comment: `size 7in,6in` is quite excessive.  Either reduce it to, say `size 5in,3in` or remove it completely.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex,terminaloptions={size 5in,4in}]
    set format '$%g$'
    set xlabel '$x$'
    set ylabel '$y$'
    set zlabel '$z$'

    set xtics offset 0,-.5
    set ytics offset 1,-.5

    set parametric
    unset key

    set xrange [-3:1]
    set yrange [-3:1]
    set zrange [-1:1]

    set urange [0:pi]
    set vrange [0:2*pi]

    r = .5

    splot r*sin(u)*cos(v),r*sin(u)*sin(v),r*cos(u)
  \end{gnuplot}
  \caption{Some gnuplot figure}
  \label{fig:blah}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: The hyphens used as minus signs are really ugly.

Comment: I tried removing the size entirely and got a very small (half the width of the document) image. I tried 5x4in and it's still the same, just more vspace between the key and the graph and the caption (something I'm trying to reduce, either).

Comment: @egreg Aesthetics improved.

Comment: @Vardonir Well, without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) there's nothing I can do for you.

Comment: just added a working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\captionsetup[]{}` command for figures or subfigures together with the `belowskip` and/or `aboveskip` options.

An example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=-15pt,belowskip=0pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions={size 7cm, 5cm}]
     ...
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{Subcaption A.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions={size 7cm, 5cm}]
     ...
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{Subcaption B.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
```

The option

```
    aboveskip=-15pt
```

subtracts whitespace above the caption